# using rectangle to select nodes on top of a zoomable map.in D3

Tags: d3.js, zooming, geo

[[This is using d3 v5 ]]

D3.zoom() automatically maps wheel and mouse clicks to operations to zoom a map. I would like to be able to draw a rectangle in the area of the map to select nodes that appear on top of the map. I need to know how to add handlers for mousedown, mousemove, mouseup, so that I can track where the rectangle should be.

I have tried the following, but the mousedown callback is never invoked.

If I remove the `.call(zoom)`, the mousedown callback is invoked, but `e` is `undefined`. I can access the event using `d3.event`, so that is not an issue.

If I move `.call(zoom)` after the `.on(`mouse*', cb)` calls, I see the mouse down, but no mouseup and only one mousemove.

I can sort of understand adding the mouse callbacks first, but I don't see why some of them are masked and others are not.
Clearly, I need some help understanding this.

```
        var zoom = d3.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([0.1, 10])
            .filter(() => !d3.event.ctrlKey) // Don't zoom/pan when ctrl is pressed
            .on("zoom", zoomed)
        ;

        container
            .call(zoom)
            .on('mousedown.zoomrect', e=>console.log('zoom', e))
            .on('mouseup.zoomrect', e=>console.log('zoom up', e))
            .on('mousemove.zoomrect', e=>console.log('zoom move', e))
        ;
```

Locating the nodes in the rectangle is a separate question, but I believe I can handle the projection and transformations.